# Best ways to fetch files/folders that shared by different people with same name using 'SharedWithMe' Microsoft Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I can fetch all the Shared Items by making a `GET` request.

`Get https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/sharedWithMe`

However, if two different people shared two items with the same name I'm just getting one item.

I can modify the names of the items using C# before fetching them but I want to know if there's a better way to get the duplicated items using Microsoft Graph API.

Comment: I do not see this behavior. I have tried with sharing files with same name from same user and different users and all files appear in the shared files response. Could you provide more context and may be try on Graph Explorer and see if you get the same thing.

Comment: thanks for trying that @Danstan I am seeing this behavior in windows when I mount the OneDrive for Business Drive.